# Running multiple feature files from runner does not honor the parallel=false tag

Tags: karate

When executing a group of feature files, within a folder, from a runner, the parallel=false flag does not appear to be honored as each feature file is ran in parallel.  without setting the runner to ONLY execute a single thread, is there another option, or is this possibly a bug?

Here are some samples for feature files, showing the parallel=false flag:

**Device complete flow**

```
Feature: Test flow for all v1 device endpoints
  Background: Test setup including authentication, pre-reqs (if any), constants, and logout settings 
    * if (skipdomain == true) { karate.logger.debug('skipDomain is set to ' + skipdomain + ' so Domain calls cannot be ran!'); karate.abort(); }

    * def dataSourceRow = karate.get('karate.properties["karate.dsRow"]', 1)
    * callonce read('../../../../constants.feature') 

    * url baseUrlDomain + domainPath
    * configure headers = headers.domain_headers
    * header host = domainHost
    
    * def endpoint = 'various'
    * def endpointMethod = 'multiple'

    @smoke @parallel=false
  Scenario: Scenario for endpoint
```

**DHCP complete flow**

```
    @domain @regression @hopper @parallel=false
Feature: Test flow for all v1 dhcp reservation endpoints
  Background: Test setup including authentication, pre-reqs (if any), constants, and logout settings 
    * if (skipdomain == true) { karate.logger.debug('skipDomain is set to ' + skipdomain + ' so Domain calls cannot be ran!'); karate.abort(); }

    * def dataSourceRow = karate.get('karate.properties["karate.dsRow"]', 1)
    * callonce read('../../../../constants.feature') 

    * url baseUrlDomain + domainPath
    * configure headers = headers.domain_headers
    * header host = domainHost
    
    * def endpoint = 'various'
    * def endpointMethod = 'multiple'

    * def randomNumber = function(min, max){ return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) + min ) }
    * def DateTime = Java.type('commonutilhelpers.DateTime')
    * def timestamp = DateTime.doWorkStatic('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm', '0')

    * def deleteDHCP =  
    """
    function(dhcpReservation){
      karate.call('this:referenceTests/DeviceDhcpReservation-DELETE.feature', { curDeviceId: dhcpReservation.macAddress});
    }
    """

    @smoke
  Scenario: Scenario for endpoint
```

**Groups complete flow**

```
    @domain @regression @hopper
Feature: Test flow for all v1 group(s) endpoints
  Background: Test setup including authentication, pre-reqs (if any), constants, and logout settings 
    * if (skipdomain == true) { karate.logger.debug('skipDomain is set to ' + skipdomain + ' so Domain calls cannot be ran!'); karate.abort(); }

    * def dataSourceRow = karate.get('karate.properties["karate.dsRow"]', 1)
    * callonce read('../../../../constants.feature') 

    * url baseUrlDomain + domainPath
    * configure headers = headers.domain_headers
    * header host = domainHost
    
    * def endpoint = 'various'
    * def endpointMethod = 'multiple'

    * def deleteGroup =  
    """
    function(group){
      karate.call('this:referenceTests/GroupsById-DELETE.feature', { groupId: group.id});
    }
    """

    @smoke @parallel=false
  Scenario: Scenario for endpoint
```

here is the timeline results showing the feature/scenarios are not being ran independently, but in parallel in threads 4, 5, and 6
[image: timeline report]

Answer (score 0):

We are working on an issue that may be the root cause of what you are observing, please go through it and understand the implications of if you use too many "global" JS functions: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2329

Some recent code changes to the `develop` branch may have fixed this already, so if you or your team can follow these instructions and provide feedback, that would greatly help: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: Our attempts appear to render the same results.  Have you seen any luck on your side?

Comment: @mike 1.4.1.RC3 is available to test

Comment: I will work with this version this coming week and let you know

Comment: Still seeing multi-thread access errors:  `* def headers = karate.callSingle('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature?' + username)
js failed:
>>
01: karate.callSingle('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature?' + username)
<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Multi threaded access requested by thread Thread[#51,pool-1-thread-7,5,main] but is not allowed for language(s) js.
- com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineException.illegalState(PolyglotEngineException.java:135)
- com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.throwDeniedThreadAccess(PolyglotContextImpl.java:1197)`

Comment: @mike read the part marked `IMPORTANT` in the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karatecallsingle

Comment: I believe this is more related to the parallel=false not being honored across feature files, so each feature is called at the same time resulting in the thread failure when calling the auth via callSingle.

Comment: @mike yes `parallel=false` only applied to scenarios within a feature. having tests that don't run in parallel is highly discouraged. it should be simple for you to refactor a new feature file as a wrapper if you really need. of course as always, we welcome code contributions. this may be a related discussion: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1921

Comment: We tried a wrapper, but that does not give a true total of the tests completed as the parent feature is the only item reported in the counts.